# Adding hostname to block list after x consecutive failures in multithreading application

Tags: java, performance, multithreading, thread-safety, atomic

I am using Callable in my code which will be called by multiple threads as shown below. Given a user id in `DataKey` object, I will find out what are the `hostnames` I can use to get the data and then I will iterate that `hostnames` list one by one to get the data.

As of now,  whenever any `RestClientException` is thrown on a particular hostname then I am adding that `hostname` to blockList so that no other thread can make a call to that hostname.

```
public class Task implements Callable<DataResponse> {

    private final DataKey key;
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger> failedCallCount = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public Task(DataKey key, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.key = key;
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public DataResponse call() {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = null;

        // construct what are the hostnames I can call basis on user id
        List<String> hostnames = some_code_here;

        for (String hostname : hostnames) {
            // If host name is null or host name is in block list, skip sending request to this host
            if (DataUtils.isEmpty(hostname) || DataMapping.isBlocked(hostname)) {
                continue;
            }
            try {
                String url = createURL(hostname);
                response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, key.getEntity(), String.class);

                resetFailedCallCount(hostname);

                // some code here to return the response if successful
            } catch (HttpClientErrorException ex) {
                // log exception
                return new DataResponse(errorMessage, error, DataStatusEnum.ERROR);
            } catch (HttpServerErrorException ex) {
                // log exception
                return new DataResponse(errorMessage, error, DataStatusEnum.ERROR);
            } catch (RestClientException ex) {
                registerFailedCall(hostname);
                if (shouldBeBlocked(hostname)) {
                // adding to block list if condition met
                  DataMapping.blockHost(hostname);
                }
            }
        }

        return new DataResponse(DataErrorEnum.SERVER_UNAVAILABLE, DataStatusEnum.ERROR);        
    }

    // can we abstract all these logics from Task class to DataMapping since that's where we are handling 
    // all the hostname whether it is blocked or not.

    private boolean shouldBeBlocked(String hostname) {
        AtomicInteger count = failedCallCount.getOrDefault(hostname, new AtomicInteger());
        return count.get() >= 5;
    }

    private void registerFailedCall(String hostname) {
        AtomicInteger newValue = new AtomicInteger();
        AtomicInteger val = failedCallCount.putIfAbsent(hostname, newValue);
        if (val == null) {
            val = newValue;
        }
        if (val.get() < 5) {
            val.incrementAndGet();
        }
    }

    private void resetFailedCallCount(String hostname) {
        AtomicInteger count = failedCallCount.get(hostname);
        if (count != null) {
            count.set(0);
        }
    }       
}
```

Below is what I have in `DataMapping` class:

```
private static final AtomicReference<ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>> blockedHosts = 
        new AtomicReference<ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>>(new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>());

public static boolean isBlocked(String hostName) {
    return blockedHosts.get().containsKey(hostName);
}

public static void blockHost(String hostName) {
    blockedHosts.get().put(hostName, hostName);
}

// this is being updated from my background thread which runs every 2 minutes
public static void replaceBlockedHosts(List<String> hostNames) {
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> newBlockedHosts = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    for (String hostName : hostNames) {
        newBlockedHosts.put(hostName, hostName);
    }
    blockedHosts.set(newBlockedHosts);
}
```

In the `call` method as shown above, I will block the hostname if it has thrown `RestClientException` five times consecutively by calling this line `DataMapping.blockHost(hostname);` otherwise I will not add it to the `blockList`.

Also I have a background thread in my library which runs every 2 minutes and that replaces the entire set of `blockedHosts` and that background thread gets the data from another service whether any `hostname` is really blocked or not. And I guess because of that reason I am using `Atomic Reference` on `blockedHosts`.

Now as my background thread is running every 2 minutes so I might get late to get the information about which machine is down or not so because of that reason, I am implementing local blocking as well. Meaning if any machine throws `RestClientException` 5 times consecutively, then only add it to block list otherwise don't add it. And if let's say `machineA` throws `RestClientException` 4 times but next time it was ok and started serving response, then the count should be reset back to zero for that machine.

In this case, my call method will be called from multiple threads so I need to make sure I am keeping the count properly for each `hostname` in case they throw `RestClientException`.

Can we simplify this code better since this library will be used under very heavy load so it has to be fast? Maximum, I will have 70-100 unique machines in total.

I am doing all the failed hostname logic in `Task` class itself which I don't think I should be doing there. Can we simplify that part and may be do everything in `DataMapping` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we simplify that part and may be do everything in DataMapping class?

Sure, but what `Data` and what `Mapping`? There's neither, it's a `BlockingManager` or whatever.

As it stands, you could simply move the code there and be done. However, `static` is mostly bad and you should create an instance and it do the work (you could use the singleton (anti-)pattern or something better).

---

You're using the map in `blockedHosts` as a `Set`. This is fine, but why to put there some dummy data when you can put there the counters?

So I'd combine and reduce it to something like

```
private final AtomicReference<ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger>> blockedHosts =
        new AtomicReference<>(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());

boolean isBlocked(String hostName) {
    AtomicInteger count = blockedHosts.get();
    return count != null && count.get() >= BLOCKING_THRESHOLD;
}

void onFailure(String hostname) {
    AtomicInteger newValue = new AtomicInteger();
    AtomicInteger val = blockedHosts.get().putIfAbsent(hostname, newValue);
    // no need to care about over-reaching 5 here
    (val == null ? newValue : val).incrementAndGet();
}

void onSuccess(String hostname) {
    blockedHosts.get().remove(hostname);
}

// this is being updated from my background thread which runs every 2 minutes
public static void replaceBlockedHosts(List<String> hostNames) {
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger> newBlockedHosts =
         new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    for (String hostName : hostNames) {
        newBlockedHosts.put(hostName, new AtomicInteger(BLOCKING_THRESHOLD));
    }
    blockedHosts.set(newBlockedHosts);
}
```

I'm pretty sure, that you need no `AtomicReference` as `volatile` would suffice. You could also use Guava's `AtomicLongMap<K>` which is just like `ConcurrentHashMap<K, AtomicLong>` but simplifies the operations you need.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. When I try to use generics as the way you suggested to initialize `blockedHosts` - I see this error : `Type mismatch: cannot convert from AtomicReference<ConcurrentHashMap<Object,Object>> to AtomicReference<ConcurrentHashMap<String,AtomicInteger>>` Any idea why? I am using Java 7 btw.

Comment: @lining The type inference seems to work for assignments only, not for arguments. So you need the type parameters for the `ConcurrentHashMap`, but (I hope) not for the `AtomicReference`.

Comment: Yes this works fine `private final AtomicReference<ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger>> blockedHosts = new AtomicReference<>(
            new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger>());` I figured it out after some time.

Comment: I do see compilation error in this method `isBlocked` method. I guess it should be like this right? `AtomicInteger count = blockedHosts.get().get(hostname);`

Comment: @lining Sure! I didn't try to compile it. so take it lightly. The idea should be clear, the details are up to you. ;)

Comment: Yeah just wanted to make sure I am doing right stuff. I am not that good in mutltithreading so still learning. Appreciated all your help.

Comment: I have extended this solution with some other requirement and posted another CR [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128606/block-a-partcular-machine-for-a-particular-period-of-time-interval-after-x-failu). See if you can help me out.